# Why doesn't changing the name of a pdf file on File Explorer (Windows 10) change the title of the file in it's metadata?

Tags: windows, pdf, metadata

I renamed a pdf file within File Explorer from X to Y. When I open the properties pop-up for the file on File Explorer, I see that the 'name' of the file is Y. However when I view the metadata for the file, the 'title' is X. Why does this happen?

I expected the title in the metadata to be Y, not X.

Comment: Likely because the two aren't linked that way - for verification, you'd likely need to search the programming man pages of Microsoft Docs or the technical data or NTFS, and/or the technical data of PDF metadata if this is PDF specific.

Comment: Well I think it's quite naturally to assume the 'title' and 'filename' are related but apparently they're not; thanks for the help. Also I'm not sure why my question was downvoted?

Comment: For downvotes, some folks downvote questions/answers without leaving a comments as to what they take issue with _(personally, I believe it should be mandatory to provide a comment if downvoting, else there's no way for the OP to address, or correct, an issue, which is counter-productive to all)_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why should the title value change if filename and title are different things?

This is the default behavior.

Comment: This answer would benefit from being fleshed out, as currently it reads more as a comment and less as an answer.

Comment: I'm voting this down. Although technically correct, its like saying: Q: Why is grass green? A: It just is.

Comment: The topic creater seems to have thought that title and filename are the same thing. I just explained that they're not.

Answer (score 3):

The metadata is part of the file contents.

This presents the following problems:

- An application developer can pretty much use any method they can dream of to embed metadata in a file.  So the way to read and update metadata is often gatewayed by the application developer, or might require a lot of effort reverse engineering or reading documentation.
- Sometimes metadata isn't simple to map to a filename.  If you rename an MP3 file, for example, a program isn't going to be able to tell if you want to update the MP3's title tag, song tag, etc.  You're expected to use a tag editor or metadata editor specific to MP3 files.
- Modifying the contents of a file by renaming it isn't necessarily something that's expected and probably not something Microsoft wants to take responsibility for if bad things happen.

All that adds up to this: you need to use an editor or the program that edits a specific file type to make those changes in the file itself.

In the mid to late 00's, Microsoft was trying to solve this problem with a technology called WinFS, which would have defined APIs that extract file metadata, put it in a separate database, and allow any application to work with it.  I think there were previews in Longhorn which was the Windows Vista preview.  However they never released a working version.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.